# How to get nested data from a JSON file in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, json, spring, nested, stripe-payments

Here is my json file:

```
{
  "id": "sub_1M3z4ZFuWMT5VbyLdhxe1SGB",
  "object": "subscription",
  "application": null,
  "application_fee_percent": null,
  "automatic_tax": {
    "enabled": true
  },
  "billing_cycle_anchor": 1671096923,
  "billing_thresholds": null,
  "cancel_at": null,
  "cancel_at_period_end": false,
  "canceled_at": null,
  "collection_method": "charge_automatically",
  "created": 1668418523,
  "currency": "eur",
  "current_period_end": 1673775323,
  "current_period_start": 1671096923,
  "customer": "cus_MnaFTQN0THNHcw",
  "days_until_due": null,
  "default_payment_method": "pm_1M3z4WFuWMT5VbyLzq2CMtRb",
  "default_source": null,
  "default_tax_rates": [],
  "description": null,
  "discount": null,
  "ended_at": null,
  "items": {
    "object": "list",
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "si_MnaFGSZRM6lgJ5",
        "object": "subscription_item",
        "billing_thresholds": null,
        "created": 1668418523,
        "metadata": {},
        "plan": {
          "id": "price_1LN1ZwFuWMT5VbyLdOZ3X83u",
          "object": "plan",
          "active": true,
          "aggregate_usage": null,
          "amount": 1900,
          "amount_decimal": "1900",
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1658180052,
          "currency": "eur",
          "interval": "month",
          "interval_count": 1,
          "livemode": false,
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_M5BxCLyY8BJinB",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_usage": null,
          "trial_period_days": null,
          "usage_type": "licensed"
        },
        "price": {
          "id": "price_1LN1ZwFuWMT5VbyLdOZ3X83u",
          "object": "price",
          "active": true,
          "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
          "created": 1658180052,
          "currency": "eur",
          "custom_unit_amount": null,
          "livemode": false,
          "lookup_key": "mini",
          "metadata": {},
          "nickname": null,
          "product": "prod_M5BxCLyY8BJinB",
          "recurring": {
            "aggregate_usage": null,
            "interval": "month",
            "interval_count": 1,
            "trial_period_days": null,
            "usage_type": "licensed"
          },
          "tax_behavior": "inclusive",
          "tiers_mode": null,
          "transform_quantity": null,
          "type": "recurring",
          "unit_amount": 1900,
          "unit_amount_decimal": "1900"
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "subscription": "sub_1M3z4ZFuWMT5VbyLdhxe1SGB",
        "tax_rates": []
      }
    ],
    "has_more": false,
    "total_count": 1,
    "url": "/v1/subscription_items?subscription=sub_1M3z4ZFuWMT5VbyLdhxe1SGB"
  },
  "latest_invoice": "in_1MFDqoFuWMT5VbyLT3EyrqPd",
  "livemode": false,
  "metadata": {},
  "next_pending_invoice_item_invoice": null,
  "on_behalf_of": null,
  "pause_collection": null,
  "payment_settings": {
    "payment_method_options": null,
    "payment_method_types": null,
    "save_default_payment_method": "off"
  },
  "pending_invoice_item_interval": null,
  "pending_setup_intent": null,
  "pending_update": null,
  "plan": {
    "id": "price_1LN1ZwFuWMT5VbyLdOZ3X83u",
    "object": "plan",
    "active": true,
    "aggregate_usage": null,
    "amount": 1900,
    "amount_decimal": "1900",
    "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
    "created": 1658180052,
    "currency": "eur",
    "interval": "month",
    "interval_count": 1,
    "livemode": false,
    "metadata": {},
    "nickname": null,
    "product": "prod_M5BxCLyY8BJinB",
    "tiers_mode": null,
    "transform_usage": null,
    "trial_period_days": null,
    "usage_type": "licensed"
  },
  "quantity": 1,
  -
  "trial_end": 1671096923,
  "trial_start": 1668418523
}
```

It's the subscription object from Stripe.

I want to create a class called SubscriptionDetails that has an amount field (in the datas plan object)

I've done that, but with my tests, I see that amount equals 0, I don't know why:
here is my class:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SubscriptionDetails implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("plan")
    private Plan plan;
    @Data
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public class Plan {
        @JsonProperty("amount")
        private int amount;
    }
}
```

Can you help me please ?

I also tried to do this:

```
@Data
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SubscriptionDetails implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("plan")
    private Plan plan;
    
}
```

with Plan object from stripe but it doesn't work.

Here is what i want to test:

```
 @Test
    public void testRetrieveSubscriptionDetails_ok()
            throws IOException, URISyntaxException, StripeClientException, BadRequestException {
        String body = FileUtils.readFileToString(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:json/subscriptions-200.json"),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        mockServer
                .expect(ExpectedCount.once(),
                        requestTo(new URI("http://localhost:80/v1/subscriptions/sub_1M3z4ZFuWMT5VbyLdhxe1SGB")))
                .andExpect(header("Accept", "application/json, application/*+json"))
                .andExpect(header("Authorization", "Bearer test")).andExpect(header("Content-Length", "0"))
                .andExpect(method(HttpMethod.GET))
                .andRespond(withStatus(HttpStatus.OK).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).body(body));
        SubscriptionDetails subscriptionDetails = this.stripeClient
                .retrieveSubscriptionDetails("sub_1M3z4ZFuWMT5VbyLdhxe1SGB");
        mockServer.verify();
        Assertions.assertThat(subscriptionDetails).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(subscriptionDetails.getTrialEnd()).isEqualTo(1671096923L);
        Assertions.assertThat(subscriptionDetails.getAmount()).isEqualTo(19.00);
```

Comment: How are you calling Stripe APIs ? using what Http Client and what Serializer? Are you using Stripe Java SDK https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java ?

Or, you are just trying to parse a local .json file, if so how are you charging it and serializing the Subscription object ?

Comment: hey @os4m37 , i'm testing with a json file :) and yes , that's not the problem because i've a test that "test" anothers values that worked, but not nested. It's only the nested values that does not work for me

Comment: Add your entire test code.

Comment: I noticed a "-" in your sample json in the 4th last line. Once I removed this the assertThat was successful (ie no exception). A System.out.println(subscriptionDetails) printed this, which looks good: SubscriptionDetails(plan=SubscriptionDetails.Plan(amount=1900))

Comment: @IgorFlakiewicz done, and I've added the test

Comment: I see that you are mocking Stripe APIs, try checking the Stripe mock server:
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-mock
Otherwise, check @JohnWilliams comment in order to solve your issue